# server side rendering in React : Is this for all the Route URLs?

Tags: html, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I am going to implement server side rendering through react application. As for as I understand the index.html will be served fast from server. I have a question. if I have a SEO url's named which is stated below, Is all the 3 URL's are rendered from the server Or It render index.html once always and then the client side take care of the URL Route ( basic | advance | test ) . what happens if I have a 3 different meta tags each. How it handled in that case ?

```
https://website.com/basic
https://website.com/advance
https://website.com/test
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical server-side rendering setup will generate the HTML server-side when the URL is requested directly by the browser.

Then, if JavaScript is supported (and doesn't fail for any reason), navigation within the app will be handled client-side by JS and not retrigger server-side rendering.

Comment: how  and what about route specific meta tags  if I shared a link in social media like face book ?

Comment: Then the client would fetch that URL and it would render server-side because it would be requested directly.

Comment: Sorry. I did not get.